# want to show laravel validation messages using vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i try to show Laravel validation error messages using vuejs. i tried to get all errors using a object.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div v-if="validationErrors">
    <ul class="alert alert-danger">
     <span style="color: #fff;">Can't save your data. List of errors here</span>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
    <li v-for="error in validationErrors" :key="error.key">{{ error }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

it shows messages but shows with error name in array. i get error message using this objects

```
if (error.response.status == 422) {
      this.validationErrors = error.response.data.errors;
}
```

error showing like this.

```
{ "name": [ "The name has already been taken." ] }
```

Comment: its because laravel returns the errors in an array for each field, the reason for the array is that each field can have multiple messages, so you can do error[0] or you can iterate over the error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li v-for="(error, index) in validationErrors" :key="`error_${index}`">{{ error[0] }}</li>
```

This would work but I would probably do some formatting before setting your error array from the response such as flatmapping and so on.